# Nested iframe won't load

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In a html document i append an `iframe` in the body (no CORS, e.g. same  url).
In the appended `iframe` i attempt to do the same thing:
the nested `iframe` element is successfully appended to the parent `iframe` body, but the content won't load.
I googled without success for info about this issue,
i made [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TilyvTTsKRyBnNutQQkf) that simply shows it.
Can anybody tell me where's the problem?

Comment: As far i can see, the iframe is added to the DOM of the iframe, but i doesn't showed (try `console.log(document)` and you'll see). What i suggest you is to find a way to use `location.reload()`.

Comment: yes, as i told, the iframe is succesfully appended, but content is not loaded, so it's impossible to do anything (location.reload neither) as `nested_iframe.contentWindow` and `nested_iframe.contentDocument` are `null` as expected because content has not been loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is doing what you are expecting,
please try to inspect your page DOM,
when you press the button the child iframe is added inside you parent iframe.

BUT:

the browser do not display an iframe inside an iframe with the same SRC, this is becouse the iframe loaded has the same source,
this script else works fine becouse the url is changed every time appending a querystring

```
document.querySelector('button')
.addEventListener('click',function(){
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getTime();
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.setAttribute('src', location.href + "?" + n );
  iframe.style.width = '100%';
  iframe.style.height = '800px';
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
})
```

Comment: Well you're just right! but why if the frame has same source it doesn't load? and why  the top frame doesn't behave the same way?

Comment: i do not found documentation about this, but is a well known security protection avoid infinite loops